# PC-BSD 9 Gnome problems

Tags: freebsd, gnome

If I'm installing any program via ports, and my screensaver starts, or goes into sleep mode, gnome will suddenly stop functioning properly.  If I move the mouse/press a key, the screen will flicker from black to wallpaper(no icons panels displaying).  If I force a shutdown and restart gnome does not start, I can log into the system through terminal.  I also get the following error saying Libpcre.so.0 can't be found.  Anyone else have this problem / know how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

For the libpcre problem i suggest to use libchk (sysutils/libchk). It checks which programs link to unresolved libraries. Reinstall those ports.

Comment: Is there an automated process which can update all the listed ports?

Comment: portupgrade -rf libpcre or portmaster -r libpcre

Comment: Ran that command.  It updated but didn't fix the problem.

Starting gem
Shared object "libpcre.so.0" not found, required by "gdk-pixbuf-query-loaders"

Comment: hm not sure why it did not work. Maybe try pkg_info -W /usr/local/bin/gdk-pixbuf-query-loaders and then reinstall that package

Comment: I've been messing around trying to get this to work and I believe I'm come across the solution.  Though, a more in depth answer would be appreciated.  I reinstalled PC BSD and decided not to install any updates, just install Apache, PHP and MySQL.  I did that, then installed updates and everything works fine.